# Adding scripts to Bigcommerce account and wishlist page

Tags: bigcommerce

Bigcommerce have a Pages API using which I am able to insert scripts to all pages except wishlist.php, account.php and  login.php . Is there any other way using which I can insert scripts into all these pages.

Comment: Check this https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00004MFXSUSA5/problem-to-add-a-script-on-checkout-page-using-script-manager and  https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Using-Script-Manager if it helps.

Comment: For reference, here's the documentation link with all of the Scripts API locations. Wishlists should be included. If you need script visibility on the account pages too, you may need to have users copy/paste code into the <head>. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/scripts-overview#scripts_scripts-visibility